# Why does serializing a NameValueCollection incur a loss of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, .net-core, namevaluecollection

For example if we have `{"Parameters":["name" : "test"]}` it will be serialized to `{"Parameters":["name"]}`. (Using `System.Text.Json`)

Why is that?

**EDIT:** See [this issue](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4655) that brought this to my attention, and the [following code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/18897890ce2cb020a71b836db030f3ed1ae57882/src/IdentityServer4/src/Infrastructure/ObjectSerializer.cs) that does serialization/deserialization.

**EDIT 2:** Added even more clarity to those that can't follow through the above given materials

```
var asd = new SomeObject()
{
    Properties = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "test1", "ok1" },
        { "test2", "ok2" }
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<SomeObject>(asd));
```

Serializes to `{"Properties":["test1","test2"]}`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it. Do you have something like a "Dictionary<string, List<object>>" ? And are you serializing it to a Json? Can you post some more details?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Please post your code in the question then.

Comment: @LeoRossetti done! Hope you now have everything needed to begin answering this question

Comment: @mjwills since when has this been mandatory? Certainly it helps make a question more "friendly", but I don't see it as a requirement, specifically for this concrete question that already includes all the relevant bits for it to be answered.

Comment: It isn't mandatory @SpiritBob. But without doing so you make it harder for people to help you. By providing a [mcve] you make it easier for people to see what you are seeing. This makes it easier for them to help you and gets you an answer sooner. Everybody wins! A lack of [mcve] reduces your effort by a little, but increases the _overall_ effort (since everyone now has to incur the effort you are trying to avoid).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376951/34092 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342051/external-link-for-code-vs-posting-code-as-an-answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339450/should-code-from-pastebin-be-edited-into-a-question may be worth a read about the downsides of external links (vs a [mcve] in the question itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the nature of `NameValueCollection`. It's iteration is over the ***key*** and not the key and value pair.

Thst's why one must do the following to get values when iterating:

```
foreach (var key in yourCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key {key} value {yourCollection[key]}.");
}
```

All serializers just iterate all enumerables, they do not understand what is actually returned.

A much better fit is the `Dictionary<string, string>`.

In your case:

```
var asd = new SomeObject()
{
    Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "test1", "ok1" },
        { "test2", "ok2" }
    }
};
```

Which will return what you expected. If you want a case insensitive dictionary, just add that as an parameter when creating it: `new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`